# How to redirect specific folder from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am struggling to redirect only my e-shop located in the folder called **shop**.
I have 2 htaccess files, one is on the domain root (the one dedicated for the corporate website) and the other one placed in the shop folder. 
I've tried many variations of the rewrite rule, but I can't make it to work...

If I put this into the shop's htaccess file i get the redirect loop error:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

This doesn't do anything in both htaccess files:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCondition %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.maindomain.com/order/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Neither this when i put it into the htaccess file located on the document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(subdirectory/.*)$ https://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Note: If it makes any difference, I have this redirect rule as well. Its located in the htaccess on the document root:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^rumako.cz$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://rumako.cz/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

And this one in the shop's htaccess:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /shop
    RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
    RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
    RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Please advise. Thanks for all answers...

Answer (score 0):

Your first rule is correct, you must only add an [`R`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r) flag

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, with that code I am having the ,,This webpage has a redirect loop" error. Any ideas what could cause this?

Comment: @hjuster This rule alone does the redirect as described in my test environment. Do you have other rules in your root or shop htacces? And do you have the `R` flag in your shop htaccess?

Comment: I have updated the question. You can see all redirects that I have in both htaccess files. Btw, thanks for helping me out...

Comment: @hjuster I copied your complete .htaccess files in my test environment and I don't see any redirect loop. When I add my `https` rule and request `http://www.example.com/shop/ijk`, it redirects properly to `https://www.example.com/shop/index.php?_route_=jkl`.